# I have a problem with switch statement, in a c++ program

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, codeblocks

Hi i made a program with switch, if i input a character to show me if is vowel or a consonant if is letter to show me if is odd or even if it's number I don't understand where is the problem, in condition is obligatory to use switch.
The problem is: It doesn't give me any error but, when i input a letter it also shows me if that letter is even or odd. How can i fix this?

```
  char n;
  cout<< "Input character : "; cin>>n;
  switch(n){
  case 'A':
  case 'a':
  case 'E':
  case 'e':
  case 'I':
  case 'i':
  case 'O':
  case 'o':
  case 'U':
  case 'u':
  cout<<n<< " vowel ."<<endl; break;
  case 'B':case 'b':case 'C':case 'c':case 'D':case 'd':
  case 'F':case 'f':case 'G':case 'g':case 'H':case 'h':
  case 'J':case 'j':case 'K':case 'k':case 'L':case 'l':
  case 'M':case 'm':case 'N':case 'n':case 'P':case 'p':
  case 'Q':case 'q':case 'R':case 'r':case 'S':case 's':
  case 'T':case 't':case 'V':case 'v':case 'W':case 'w':
  case 'X':case 'x':case 'Y':case 'y':case 'Z':case 'z':
  cout<<n<< " is consonant ."<<endl; break;
  }

  switch(n%2 ==0){
  case 0: cout<<n<< " is even"; break;
  case 1: cout<<n<< " is odd"; break;
  default:cout<<n<< " is simbol"<<endl; break;
  }
```

Comment: Hint: a `char` is just an integer value and `n%2` has only two possible results: 0 or 1, the default case can't be hit in the second switch. You need to find a way to determine wether `n` represents is a digit or letter.

Comment: You need to *nest* the `switch` statements.    Also, there are varioius functions in the standard library for checking if a character is alphabetic, uppercase, lowercase, digits, etc.   Using those would simplify your code considerably.

Comment: for example, what functions?

Comment: Providing [mcve] would be very helpful. You can use https://godbolt.org/ . Describing desired behavior in details would help too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want. The text "is simbol" will never be written. Feel free to add it. :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

int main(void)
{

    char n;
    std::cout << "Input character : "; std::cin >> n;
    switch (n)
    {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
    case 'E':
    case 'e':
    case 'I':
    case 'i':
    case 'O':
    case 'o':
    case 'U':
    case 'u':
        std::cout << n << " vowel ." << std::endl; break;
    case 'B':case 'b':case 'C':case 'c':case 'D':case 'd':
    case 'F':case 'f':case 'G':case 'g':case 'H':case 'h':
    case 'J':case 'j':case 'K':case 'k':case 'L':case 'l':
    case 'M':case 'm':case 'N':case 'n':case 'P':case 'p':
    case 'Q':case 'q':case 'R':case 'r':case 'S':case 's':
    case 'T':case 't':case 'V':case 'v':case 'W':case 'w':
    case 'X':case 'x':case 'Y':case 'y':case 'Z':case 'z':
        std::cout << n << " is consonant ." << std::endl; break;

    case '0':
    case '2':
    case '4':
    case '6':
    case '8':
        std::cout << n << " is even"; break;

    case '1':
    case '3':
    case '5':
    case '7':
    case '9':
        std::cout << n << " is odd"; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's wrong Implementation. Why are you checking for even/odd and vowe/consonant in same switch statement.

Comment: yes, but i need to show me any number if is odd or even, not just the first 9

Answer (score 0):

For simple vowel/consonant:

```
char n;
cin >> n;
switch(n){
    case 'A': case 'a': case 'E': case 'e': case 'I': case 'i': case 'O': case 'o':
    case 'U': case 'u':
    cout << " IS VOWEL \n";
    // Any other alphabet except a,e,i,o,u is consonant.
    default: cout << "IS Consonant\n";
}
```

For even Odd you can use this:

If you want to take another number input from user then check even/odd

```
int num;
cin >> num;
num = num%2;
```

Else Want to check ascii of char n is even/odd

```
int num = int(n)%2; // n is the char declared above and int(num) is ascii of n
```

Following is generic switch statement:

```
switch(num)
{
    case 0: cout << "Number is Even\n"; break;
    case 1: cout << "Number is Odd\n"; break;
}
// This will be generic
```

Comment: i want to detect if its vowel, consonant, even or odd from a single cin>>

Comment: basically what i want to do is introduce a character and if its letter to detect if is vowel or consonant or if its number to detect if its odd or even in a single program, with switch

Comment: my program do that but automatically checks the letter if its even or odd in ASCII

Comment: how can you check number is even/odd. You are defining type char at start. So, you want to check if ascii of that number is even odd ?

Comment: no , i want to check if a number i introduce is odd or even